# Access /sdcard in Android 4.2

Tags: java, android

I am developing an app that needs direct access to the root folder of the sdcard, however it seems in Android 4.2, the standard /sdcard directory now points to an "emulated" sdcard specific to the user running the app. This is not good, as my app requires access to a file that is stored on the top level of the sdcard. Does anyone know how to directly access the sdcard in Android 4.2?

Comment: Is this an actual removable SD card?  On the 4.x devices I've seen, there really is no sdcard, only an emulation of one within the internal storage volume, so the goal would be meaningless.  If there's a physical card you could look with the 'mount' command of the adb shell and see how it's being handled.

Comment: You seem to be misunderstanding. There is always an /sdcard partition, even if it is virtual. But with the 4.2 update, the handling of /sdcard is completely different. Accessing the sdcard partition (in code) no longer points you to the *real* /sdcard, it points you to a virtual "partition" of the sdcard which is specific to the current user.


Keep in mind that the app I'm developing works just fine on Android versions below 4.2, regardless of device.

Comment: See this post by Koushik Dutta (the developer of ROM Manager) where he complains about the same issue. https://plus.google.com/103583939320326217147/posts/D7mZBjTJj5j

Comment: See https://android.googlesource.com/platform/docs/source.android.com/+/master/src/tech/storage/index.md "At boot, the system mounts a single emulated external storage FUSE daemon at
`EMULATED_STORAGE_SOURCE`, which is hidden from apps.  After the Zygote forks,
it bind mounts the appropriate user-specific subdirectory from under the FUSE
daemon to `EMULATED_STORAGE_TARGET` so that external storage paths resolve
correctly for the app.  Because an app lacks accessible mount points for other
users’ storage, they can only access storage for the user it was started as." so you likely need root.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the storage directory as a File type? (`java.io.File`)

If so, you can get the external storage (Typically SD card, but will be main storage on phones with no SD card) by using code such as this in your method:

```
File path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
```

Additionally, access of storage requires `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your Android Manifest - with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` being needed if any data is modified. Here are these permissions as they would appear in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Sources:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

Comment: That's what I currently use, but the issue is that in Android 4.2 it is redirected not to the actual root of the /sdcard (ExternalStorageDirectory) partition, but to a special user-specific location on the /sdcard (ExternalStorageDirectory) partition.

Comment: Aah, I see - sorry I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am misunderstanding your question, however, with my Nexus Galaxy running Android 4.2.1 I can access my sd card  using `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`. The returned directory is `/storage/emulated/0`, but the content is that of `/sdcard`.

Comment: There is some doc about storages, but for 4.4 source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/config-example.html and doubleencore.com/2014/03/android-external-storage